# Boundary conditions in minimizing Dirichlet energy for an image processing problem.

Tags: calculus-of-variations, image-processing, computer-vision

Suppose 
$$\mathcal{L} =\mathcal{L}(x,y,u,u_x,u_y) = \frac{1}{2} \lVert \nabla u \rVert^2$$

and I want to find $u$ such that the functional

$$
E(u)=\int_{\Omega} \mathcal{L}dxdy
$$

is minimized, computing the variational derivative leads me to

$$
\frac{\delta E}{\delta u} = \int_{\partial \Omega}(u_y - u_x)h d\gamma -\int_{\Omega} \Delta u h dxdy 
$$

therefore the $u$ function I'm looking for is given by

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) u = 0 & u (x,y) \in \partial \Omega \\
\Delta u = 0 & (x,y) \in \text{Int}(\Omega)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Though the question might be silly, I wonder how the operator

$$
A =\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}
$$

might be discretized, my attempt would be using be applying the Sobel masks in pixels at $\partial \Omega$ and adding the results, would this be correct? Or is that operator something know that I'm missing? I thought at the beginning it was the divergence operator, but I was wrong since $u$ is a real valued function.

**Update** (Full derivation of the integral)

We have
$$
\frac{E(u + \alpha h) - E(u)}{\alpha} = \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{\Omega} \mathcal{L}(x,y,u+\alpha h,u_x+\alpha h_x, u_y+\alpha h_y) -\mathcal{L}(x,y,u,u_x, u_y)dxdy = \\ \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u}h + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}h_x + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y}h_y dxdy = \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u}h dxdy + \int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}h_x + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y}h_y dxdy.
$$

Consider the integral

$$
\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}h_x + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y}h_y dxdy
$$

observing

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}h_x = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}h\right) - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x} h
$$

and likewise for $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y}h_y$ we have
$$
\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}h_x + \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y}h_y dxdy = \int_{\partial \Omega} \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}\right)h d\gamma - \int_{\Omega} \left( \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x} + \frac{d}{dy} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y}\right)h dxdy
$$

Taking the limit for $\alpha \to 0$ yields

$$
\frac{\delta E}{\delta u} = \int_{\Omega} \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u} - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x} - \frac{d}{dy} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y}\right)h dxdy + \int_{\partial \Omega} \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x}\right)h d\gamma
$$

And explicit computation of the partial derivatives of $\mathcal{L}$ yields to expression above.

Comment: You can use for example Sobel filters to approximate derivative. But what does that directional derivative have to do with gradient?

Comment: I might be missing something, where do you see the directional derivative? I want to minimize the squared norm of the gradient, I haven't used directional derivative. Or are you talking about the variational derivative?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ will act as a directional derivative 45% degrees. Just try adding two Sobel filters together and you will see.

Comment: A gradient takes d/dx and d/dy separately on u and creates a vector field from them, not adding them together.

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean. Basically that equation comes from minimizing the boundary term, where I assume $h$ (the increment) isn't necessarily $h = 0$, hence that quantity is minimized when $$u_x + u_y  = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)u = 0.$$ Is this wrong?

Comment: I am more used to solving these in terms of big block matrices, i.e. assume outer product with $\nabla$ is performed by some matrix $\bf M$ and then express solution as equation system involving such $\bf M$ matrices. I don't know where the sum comes from in this derivation.

Comment: I'm deriving the equation, but I want to end up with the a linear system as well.

Comment: It is good you show what you tried, it makes it much easier for people to help.

Comment: I think the operator $A$ was wrong, I think the correct one is $$A = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$

Comment: Probably the boundary conditions should be interpreted as the whole integral $$\int_{\partial \Omega} \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_y} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_x} \right) h d\gamma = \int_{\partial \Omega} \left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{u}}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial \mathcal{u}}{\partial x} \right) h d\gamma$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variation should be:
$$
\delta\int_\Omega \frac12|\boldsymbol{\nabla} u|^2 = -\int_\Omega\Delta u\ \delta u +
\int_{\partial\Omega}\boldsymbol{\nabla} u\cdot\boldsymbol n\ \delta u
$$

So the second equation is
$$
\left.\boldsymbol{n}\cdot\boldsymbol{\nabla} u = 0 \right|_{\partial\Omega},
$$
where $\boldsymbol n$ is a normal vector to $\partial\Omega$. Or in other words that gradient flow $\boldsymbol{\nabla} u$ should be perpendicular to the boundary $\partial\Omega$.

Discretization of this depends on many things. If boundary is simple (rectangular), you can just set one of the sobel values to zero. If the boundary is complex, you might try to detect pixels of boundaries, calculate the tangent there and write linear equations on sobel values.

**Edit**

Consider your integral
$$
I = \int_\Omega\left(\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial u_x}h_x+\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial u_y}h_y\right)dx\,dy = 
\int_\Omega (F\,h_x+G\,h_y)\,dx\,dy =\\
 \int_\Omega\left(\frac\partial{\partial x}(F h)-F_xh+\frac\partial{\partial y}(G h)-G_yh\right)dx\,dy = \\ 
 -\int_\Omega h\left(F_x+G_y\right)dx\,dy +  \int_\Omega\left(\frac\partial{\partial x}(F h)+\frac\partial{\partial y}(G h) \right)dx\,dy.
$$

Green's theorem for second integral gives
$$
\int_{\partial\Omega}-Ghdx+Fhdy = \int_{\partial\Omega}h(F\,dn_x + G\,dn_y).
$$
where $\boldsymbol{dn} = (dy, -dx)$

Comment: I was about to end up with the same conclusion, if you could derive the boundary term properly so I can see my mistake that would be awesome.

Comment: And the boundary isn't rectangular unfortunately

Comment: Also, shouldn't you get $n\cdot \nabla u = 0$? (normal instead of tangent)

Comment: You are right about the normal vs tangent. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Great! thank you

Comment: Just one more clarification, the condition $\nabla u \cdot n = 0$ means directional derivative wrt the normal direction in the boundary, which translates into computing $(\cos \theta G_x + \sin \theta G_y)*u$, since the filter is steerable (or by definition of directional derivative), right?

Comment: Yes. However, you probably want to calculate $G_xu$ and $G_yu$ once and then just mix them in the boundary points with appropriate weights (cos, sin)

Comment: sure, of course. Just compute $G_x u, G_y u$ once and mix the values accordingly.